# warning: 'webkitIDBIndex' is deprecated

Tags: css, webkit

I'm getting the following warning message in my console:

```
'webkitIDBIndex' is deprecated. Please use 'IDBIndex' instead.
```

What exactly does this entail? I've never heard of "webkitIDBIndex" before.

For cross-browser functionality I sometimes use, for example, `-webkit-border-radius` in addition to the normal `border-radius`. Does it have something to do with that?